# Excel Data Not inserted to sql database in c# web app But no exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm write a web app to upload excel data to sql database. The application run without errors. But the excel data doesn't hit to the database. But when i run the app second time it give error as 'violation of primary key constraint 'PK_Category'.Can't insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Category'. But how that possible because in the first time no data gone to data base.

here is my code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string excelUploder()        {


        string status;
        string fileparth;
        string json;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
      //  get the file path of excel file as ‘fileparth’
        fileparth = jo.Value<string>("uplaodFile");
        string conString = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileparth);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'", fileparth);


                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'", fileparth);

                break;

        }

        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("CatCode", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("CatName", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("HieCode",typeof(string)) });
     //CatCode,CatName,HieCode are the excel table column values and also as same as the name of db table 
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GatePassDemoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Category";

                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CatCode", "CatCode");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CatName", "CatName");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("HieCode", "HieCode");
                    con.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                        status = "Succesfully copyed";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        status = e.ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

this my excel table

[image]

here is my db table

[image]

this is the error i get the second time i try to uplode the excel to db. but in the first time i try to upload the excel data to database nothing save in db tables.
[image]

this is my javascript function which call for above function

```
   function Uploder() {

  //fileuploder is the html controller  
  alert(document.getElementById('fileUploder').value);
  var jsonData = { "uplaodFile": document.getElementById('fileUploder').value };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("excelUploder", "TransportRequest")',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
        });
}
```

my html code

```
            <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40" id="fileUploder">
```

please help me to solve this issue. thank you .

Comment: Man, it looks like the data is actually inserted inside the database. Try to execute a `SELECT` command on the table.

Comment: Can you try debugging and confirm that at the point of doing sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData) that dtExcelData actually contains data?

Comment: @king.code ,  when come the secound error it look like the data is gone for table for 1st time try to uplode the data to db. but they were not in the table

Comment: @sr28 in that point sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData)      dtExcelData  is showed as null when i debug. how that happen please help me to solve this issue. thanks

Comment: Can you debug your method and check your connection string is pointing to right database you are looking for

Comment: What is your 'sheet1' returning?

Comment: I would try filling the datatable differently. Rather than creating columns etc, I'd simply create the datatable (no columns) and use the OleDbDataAdapter and use FillSchema(dtExcelData, SchemaType.Source) and then use the fill method. See if that works.

Comment: thank you all i solve the problem it cose a proble in db connection